# Tempus dominus from bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have the next problem:

[image]

I'm trying to install Tempus dominus of bootstrap but I have these bug when I try to put it, the modal body don't cover all the calendar, and in the footer, it would show a clock icon for additional time.
What do you believe could be the wrong whit it, I'm leaving my scripts

```
d meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/brand/favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700">
  <!-- Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Page plugins -->
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/argon.css?v=1.2.0" type="text/css">

  <!-- Full Callendar -->

  <link href='fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar/list/main.css">



  <script src='fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar/interaction/main.js'></script>
  <script src='fullcalendar/timegrid/main.js'></script>
  <script src="fullcalendar/list/main.js"></script>


  <script src="js/theme-chooser.js"></script>
  <script src="json/events.json"></script>


  <!-- ELemeentos añadidos para el datepicker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />


These are the header scripts

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
      <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/brand/favicon.png" type="image/png">
      <!-- Fonts -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700">
      <!-- Icons -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" type="text/css">
      <!-- Page plugins -->
      <!-- CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/argon.css?v=1.2.0" type="text/css">
    
      <!-- Full Callendar -->
    
      <link href='fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
      <link href='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
      <link href='fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar/list/main.css">
    
    
    
      <script src='fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
      <script src='fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>
      <script src='fullcalendar/interaction/main.js'></script>
      <script src='fullcalendar/timegrid/main.js'></script>
      <script src="fullcalendar/list/main.js"></script>
    
    
      <script src="js/theme-chooser.js"></script>
      <script src="json/events.json"></script>
    
    
      <!-- ELemeentos añadidos para el datepicker -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
    
    
      <!-- jquery JS -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap js -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Now the body's scripts

```
<script>
  $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default = $.extend({}, $.fn.datetimepicker.Constructor.Default, {
            icons: {
                time: 'far fa-clock',
                date: 'far fa-calendar',
                up: 'far fa-arrow-up',
                down: 'far fa-arrow-down',
                previous: 'far fa-chevron-left',
                next: 'far fa-chevron-right',
                today: 'far fa-calendar-check-o',
                clear: 'far fa-trash',
                close: 'far fa-times'
            } });
</script>


  <!-- dashboard Scripts -->
  <!-- Core -->
  <script src="assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/jquery-scroll-lock/dist/jquery-scrollLock.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Optional JS -->
  <script src="assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.extension.js"></script>
  <!-- dashboard JS -->
  <script src="assets/js/argon.js?v=1.2.0"></script>
</body>

</html>
```